# Classic layout of dynamic header, content and footer

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I know this has been asked a thousand times and I've been digging through various methods for a while now.

Basically, I have a header and a footer with unknown height and I need content to fill what's left. And I need to be able to do what I want within the content.

```
<header>Header</header>

<div class="content">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="something">Something</div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3nvjqvg/

I used to do it with display: table-row and it was all fine but now I need to support IE10 and in IE10 I cannot make a div inside content that would have 100% height - it doesn't respect it's parent height and scrollbars appear (check above fiddle in IE10).

So now I thought, aight, it's time to try flexboxes since they are universally supported these days. Here's my fiddle:

```
<header>Header</header>

<div class="content">
    <div class="something">Something</div>
</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waLwfthb/

With proper prefixes this works even in IE. However in Chrome I cannot get  to fill the entire flex container.

I don't want to do any nested flexes or anything more complex than that, I just want this basic layout so I can start working inside content class as if it was my entire page and forget about header and footer. Is it still that hard to do in this day and age? I might be missing something really simple, hope somebody would be able to help. I would think that this is a pretty widespread usage of flex but it seems most of the questions and answers are about more specific situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody stumbles upon this question later, here is how you can do it (stupid me for not thinking of it earlier, I guess my brains were boiling)

You would need to use absolute positioning. Here's a final fiddle that works in IE10, FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari:
http://jsfiddle.net/waLwfthb/5/

```css
html {
    height: 100%;  
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

header {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}

header:hover {
    
}

header:hover::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 20px;
    background: white;
    content: 'I am a dropdown menu';
    display: inline-block;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
}

.something {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

footer {
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<footer>Footer</footer>

<div class="content">
    <div class="something">Something</div>
</div>

<header>I'm a menu, hover you mouse</header>
```

***A little explanation:*** Since I had to use relative/absolute positioning within content, it gets above everything else. This is not ideal since in your header you might have dropdown menus that would get behind content. I also try to avoid explicit z-indexes, so I've put those blocks in reverse order in html and used flex-direction: column-reverse; That complicates css/html a little bit, moving it further from a generic example, but it is more if a real case scenario.

As a bonus, here's a jsfiddle with navigation pane, content and a sidebar:
http://jsfiddle.net/waLwfthb/6/

Hope that would help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove `height: 100%` from the child div and add `display: flex` to the container.

This works for me in Chrome:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    background: green;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    background: pink;
    display: flex;
}

.something {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
    
<div class="content">
  <div class="something">Something</div>
</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I'm using Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m which is the latest one. Doesn't wortk on my work PC, neither home one, yellow "something" block is still just a one line and doesn't fill up the pink flex content block.

Comment: That would still leave me in "flex environment" and any other div that I would put into "something" will not be able to have height set in percentages. However I, for some reason, didn't think of absolute positioning last night, I guess I was just too tired :P Answered my own question with a working solution in case somebody would stumble upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
I took the value of the windows height and made javascript change the value of the content, which separates both the header and footer apart, and you can still use it regularly.

Hope this helps!

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function()
{
      if(document.readyState == "complete")
      {
          var  myw = window.innerWidth;
          var  myh = window.innerHeight;
          
          document.getElementById("content").style.width  = "auto";
          document.getElementById("content").style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
        
          //alert("done");
      }
}
```

```css
*
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: verdana;
}

ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:link{text-decoration:none; color:#44f;}
a:link:hover{text-decoration:none; color:#aaf;}

#content
{
  position:relative;
}
  
li
{
   display:inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    
    <div id="footer">
      All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I am looking for a pure css solution. I'm fine with using flex in my case, but if somebody is restricted with old browser versions they can use your solution.